# error while using array of pointers instead of 2 dimensional array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

the following code crashes if i give array of pointer here is there any other way to accept value through array of pointers or did i do somethong wrong here

the run this program after compiling you should type
objectname -numberoflines

```
  //program to print first n lines of string using command  line arguement
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int less(int x,int y);`enter code here`
int main(int argc,char* argv[])
 {
     int i,j,n,num;
    char *lines[100];/*if I use two dimensional array here the code compiles
    char nu[6];

 // the whole for loop is for checking error in n
    for(i=1,n=strlen(argv[1]);i<n;i++)
    {
            if(argv[1][i]=='.')
            {
                    printf("your input was not correct \n");
                    return 0;
            }
            if(argv[1][i]=='-')
            {
                    printf("your input was not correct \n");
                    return 0;
            }
            if(isalpha(argv[1][i])!=0)
            {
                printf("your input was not correct indeed");
                return 0;
            }
    }
    printf("\t\t application to print number of last n lines \n\n\n");
    printf("enter the number of lines\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("enter your lines \n");
    for(j=0;(n<100)&&(j<=n);j++)
    {
            gets(lines[j]);
    }
    strcpy(nu,argv[1]);
    nu[0]=' ';
    num=atoi(nu);
    num=(less(num,n));
    for(i=0;i<=num;i++)
    {
            printf("%s",lines[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
int less(int x,int y)
{
    int z;
    return (z=(x>y?y,printf("your input lines are less\n"):x));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that when you write

```
char *lines[100];
```

You create an array of 100 `char*` pointers. These pointers have no memory allocated for them and they point to a random location. Writing to that location(using `gets` in your program) invokes Undefined Behavior.

To fix it, allocate memory for each pointer using

```
for(i=0 ; i<100 ; i++)
    lines[i]=malloc(AMOUNT_OF_BYTES_TO_ALLOCATE);
```

And later, after the use is over, free the allocated memory using

```
for(i=0 ; i<100 ; i++)
    free(lines[i]);
```

The reason that it worked when you used a two dimensional array is that you create an array of array of `char` for which memory is automatically allocated in the stack.